# DoCheck in component do detect changes in a service

Tags: angular, service, components

I recently had this problem of "how to detect a change in a service, and make it visible in my component".

I solved it using DoCheck() :

```
DoCheck(){
    if( this.componentVar != this.myService.serviceVar){
         this.componentVar = this.myService.serviceVar;
    }
}
```

And it works well! But I didn't see anywhere that it was a good method, so this is my question:
Do you think this solution is a good one?

Comment: Probably easier on the client to subscribe to an observable on the service and drive the change or comparison from there. DoCheck is called a great deal. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck for the downsides of hooking in that way

Answer (score 0):

$doCheck is considered a way of "watching" to replace $scope watch. I can see your code bind your component to service variable. This is close coupling and it is not recommended. Also it runs at every digest cycle that is often causing performant issues. A better way is to use one way binding on your component variable. So your component become dump component that are more reusable.

```js
var childComponent = {
  bindings: { componentVar: '<' },
  controller: function () {
    this.$onChanges = function (changes) {
           if(changes.componentVar){
                   //do something here
            }
    };
  }
};

angular
  .module('app')
  .component('childComponent', childComponent);
```

Comment: Make sure your snippet actually *runs* by including the appropriate Angular version and anything else needed. Otherwise convert it to a normal code block.